Equivalent Russian / Soviet books for HC Verma "Concepts of Physics"
Yeah.. it is in the question. HC Verma "Concepts of Physics" is one of the most popular physics books in India. I didn't like that book much and I am looking for a Russian alternative to This book.
The word "equivalent" means it teaches all the same topics inside the book. Why am I looking for Russian you might ask? Cause Russian books were written in 1970-90s so they are old and provide a little  unconventional technique to the conventional way of learning the subject ( I have experienced it myself in  calculus by tarasov). Russians also focus on the concept much more.. even old American books are also viable provided they belong to the same era.

I.E Irodov has written 2 theory books on mechanics and electrodynamics. Although they are not as detailed as HCV they are quite crisp and often invoke unconventional ideas to solve high school level problems.Although the level of the problems is much higher.
For American alternatives you have probably heard of Resnick Halliday(Krane/Walker). University physics is also good.
And ofcourse if you want to dig deeper in any particular topic such as mechanics or electromagnetism there are more advanced books on the undergrad level.
